# What questions with very simple answers should be flagged for?

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts

There are always a lot of questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730863/sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-root127-0-0-1-using-password), where problem is just in wrong config parameters, typos and so on. They don't bring much helpful information for future users, so they should be closed or removed (should they)?

I want to understand what exactly should I flag that kind of questions for? Off-topc, low quality, maybe something else?

Comment: @Servy's approach is the right use-case to go in most cases but related question is a bit different in my opinion; it indeed can help future visitors. Users that try to use *auto created* configuration files may have the same issue. Best thing to do is to edit the question and put it in a better shape (a better title maybe) so google-ers will reach it and will not possibly try to re-ask it on SO.

Comment: There is already **a lot** of duplicates of this question. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsymfony2%5D+SQLSTATE+1045 The provided question should more likely be flagged as a duplicate, but my question was about such questions in general. And about helping future visitors, don't even know. For example, If you got access denied exception, It instantly becomes obviously, that problem is in the configuration. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing questions that meet this close reason:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

That would cover things like typos, assuming it is in a manner unlikely to help future visitors.

Another option worth considering, if the problem is in fact related to information not provided in the question (i.e. in config information not provided, or in other code elsewhere in the application):

> This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.